# No Sound on Ubuntu 15.10 running on Acer CB3-111-670 Chromebook

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, acer, chromebook

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 on an Acer CB3-111-670 Chromebook.  I am running directly off of the internal ssd after following this guide:
https://wiki.galliumos.org/Installing/Preparing#Bay_Trail and installing this custom firmware:
https://wiki.galliumos.org/Support/BayTrail
Then instead of booting the GalliumOS USB (it wasn't recognized,) I booted from my Ubuntu 15.10 USB instead.

Everything works out of the box except audio.  Under 'Sound' settings, my 'Speakers' show up as byt-max98090, but when I press 'test sound' no audio is heard.  Also Youtube videos play fine, but again, no sound.

Just wondering if there is a workaround for getting the audio to work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by following these instructions. The only thing I did differently was run:

`sudo alsa force-unload`  (as mentioned by Parker J. Stone in the comments.)

INSTEAD OF the original step of running: `sudo killall alsactl`

to kill alsa.  All other steps were ran as written by the OP.

Here is the link:

https://plus.google.com/+JamesFuBEEFCAKE/posts/Tf4Pc5Z8reH

Also note: upon reboot after following the mentioned instructions, I got the drum sound from Ubuntu. Then after logging in, I tried to play a YouTube video and got no sound.  I clicked on my sound card in 'Sound' under 'System Settings' then clicked on 'Test Sound' and heard "left speaker" as well as "right speaker."  After doing this, I went back to YouTube and the video played correctly with sound!  Thus far, everything is working GREAT!

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1833116

```
git clone https://github.com/plbossart/UCM.git
cd UCM
cp -r chtmax98090/ /usr/share/alsa/ucm/
alsactl store
```

after reboot sound card should be detected

https://askubuntu.com/a/1152918/968224