# No Sound on Intel Ubuntu 18.04 chromebook

Tags: sound, 18.04

I Have downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on to my computer (which is a Intel Chromebook) I have looked all over the web (including ask ubuntu) but have no answers that work. Can someone please help!!!

Thanks!!

Comment: It would help to specify which processor type, such as Cherrytail, etc, you are working with. I have had no luck with my Intel Cherrytail sound card drivers yet.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help but I also had this issue when trying to use ubuntu 16.04 with an acer chromebook

The solution was listed here in this answer - [No Sound on Ubuntu 15.10 running on Acer CB3-111-670 Chromebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720516/no-sound-on-ubuntu-15-10-running-on-acer-cb3-111-670-chromebook)

I have only just installed xubuntu 18.04 not got round to trying to get the sound working myself.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with my Asus chromebook. Sound worked fine under chromeos, but only showed "dummy output" under pulseaudio. Managed to fix this about a year ago, after lots of research. I am dual-booting in the traditional sense (Ubuntu is on an SD card), so not sure if my fix works in crouton or chroot situations too. Regardless, here's what I did to fix it:

1. Created live USB with GalliumOS.
2. Booted chromebook from that live USB.
3. Tested sound to make sure GalliumOS actually supported my hardware.
4. Once I confirmed sound worked, I copied the "/usr/share/alsa", "/usr/share/alsa-base", and "/var/lib/alsa" folders to a second USB.
5. Rebooted into the SD card (Xubuntu 18.04).
6. Opened terminal and executed the following command: `pgrep alsa`. This is supposed to disable alsamixer to prevent issues with the next step.
7. Copied the saved GalliumOS folders to their respective locations in the SD card system.
8. Reloaded alsa. `sudo alsa force-reload`.
9. Tested sound to confirm fix worked.

It goes without saying, but be sure to save a copy of the recipient system's alsa folders before replacing them.

If this doesn't work, you may need to generate an asound.state file before step 4 (I can't confirm this now, since I reformatted the GalliumOS usb). Instructions on doing this are in the "alsa info" link below.

If you want a really easy solution, just install GalliumOS. It's Xubuntu redesigned specifically for chromebooks.

Tested computer was Asus C202SA (Braswell chipset). System was Xubuntu 18.04.4 installed on an SD card. Dual-boot accomplished by entering developer mode and using the Mr. Chromebox script to flash legacy bios.

**Reference material:**

Alsa info: [No Audio on Acer Chromebook 14 under Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974073/no-audio-on-acer-chromebook-14-under-ubuntu-17-10)

GalliumOS site: https://galliumos.org/

**For those interested:**

Info on developer mode and script: https://www.howtogeek.com/279308/how-to-restore-your-chromebooks-original-bios-and-software/

Script site: https://mrchromebox.tech/

Comment: Just a quick note to say that, while this may work in specific circumstances, copying and pasting stuff like this between OSs / distros is a recipe for disaster, and could break your system and render it unusable.