# Ubuntu 18.04 Only audio option is HDMI and does not work

Tags: 18.04, sound, chromebook

I've looked everywhere and can't solve this problem. I'm really new to advanced computer stuff and linux. I don't know what to include so just ask and I'll include it. I'm running ubuntu 18.04 on a CB3-111 acer Chromebook. In settings the only audio option is HDMI and it doesn't work. Originally there was only dummy audio as an option but I followed a tutorial that brought up HDMI as an option. I couldn't find the tutorial again but it only fixed the HDMI. I want to use internal audio and headphones but neither work. This is the return from the terminal command:

```
$ lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
```

and:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtmax98090 [chtmax98090], device 0: Audio (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtmax98090 [chtmax98090], device 1: Deep-Buffer Audio (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What tutorial did you follow? Did you use crouton to install?

Comment: I did not use crouton. I used a bootable usb drive with Ubuntu 18.04 and followed this tutorial for the bios: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+convert+a+generic+Chromebook+to+Linux+OS/108259

Comment: Found the tutorial that replaced dummy output with HDMI: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html?m=1

Comment: I'm working on finding an answer but in the mean time, try plugging in a device to the headphone jack or unplugging and replugging the device to see if that refreshes things for you. I had a dell laptop that would switch to hdmi every time I would plug into and external monitor and would not show any other options until I would plug the headphones in or unplug and replug the headphones in. It seems you have another driver besides the intel one and I found some info but I have to work out some stuff.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Please take a look here and see if these instructions work: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acer_CB3-131_Chromebook

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1833116

```
git clone https://github.com/plbossart/UCM.git
cd UCM
cp -r chtmax98090/ /usr/share/alsa/ucm/
alsactl store
```

after reboot sound card should be detected