# Audio (chtmax98090) still not working after fix

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have been using a Chromebook 11e with Ubuntu 19.04 installed on it for the past year. The entire time I have had it the sound has not worked. Audio over Bluetooth and HDMI work perfectly, but the speaker and headphone jack do not.

I have followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122612/ubuntu-18-04-only-audio-option-is-hdmi-and-does-not-work) to try to fix the audio, which did not work. The tutorial is not for my exact computer, but it has the same sound card. After following the tutorial sound started to come out of my headphones, but nothing intelligible. It sounded almost like if you talked into a fan, but worse.

Today I was trying to fix the issue again, but after killing pulseaudio and restarting it NO audio is coming out.

Since it has been over a year since I got this computer I have tried a plethora of fixes for pulseaudio to no avail. I do not remember everything I have tried, but I most likely have tried all of the basic fixes like reinstalling pulseaudio and alsa.

Thanks for any help, and sorry for being so similar to previous questions.

**EDIT**

This is the output I get when I enter `sudo alsaucm -c byt-max98090 set _verb HiFi set _enadev Speakers`

```
ALSA lib main.c:432:(execute_sequence) unable to open ctl device 'hw:bytmax98090'
ALSA lib main.c:1712:(set_verb_user) error: failed to initialize new use case: HiFi
alsaucm: error failed to set _verb=HiFi: No such device
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/plbossart/UCM.git (open this in your browser)

Download / clone the folder, extract downloaded file to any folder of your choice, open a terminal in the extracted folder, (note your sound card might be `byt-max98090` or any other but will display as `chtmax98090` in `alsamixer`) the `ucm` folder contains over 15 different sound card configs), then enter these command lines :

```
sudo cp -r chtmax98090/ /usr/share/alsa/ucm/
sudo alsaucm -c chtmax98090 set _verb HiFi set _enadev Speakers
sudo alsaucm -c chtmax98090 set _verb HiFi set _enadev Headphone
sudo alsactl store
```

If your sound card is really `chtmax98090` it will work for you.
If it's not just, do a liitle digging about your model and see its soundcard, else try with all the sound cards configs in the UCM folder.

If your find out your soundcard is `byt-max98090` instead of `chtmax98090`, just edit the name in the code according to how its named in the folder, this will be what you will use incase your sound card is `byt-max98090`

- `sudo cp -r byt-max98090/ /usr/share/alsa/ucm/`
- `sudo alsaucm -c byt-max98090 set _verb HiFi set _enadev Speakers`
- `sudo alsaucm -c byt-max98090 set _verb HiFi set _enadev Headphone`
- `sudo alsactl store`

Comment: I get the following error message: `ALSA lib main.c:432:(execute_sequence) unable to open ctl device 'hw:bytmax98090'
ALSA lib main.c:1712:(set_verb_user) error: failed to initialize new use case: HiFi
alsaucm: error failed to set _verb=HiFi: No such device`. I get a different one for the if i try it without the byt, but there is not enough characters to type that.