# chtmax98090 - no sound on various distros, but sound on ONE

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm seeing the exact same problem listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189122/audio-chtmax98090-still-not-working-after-fix) on multiple flavors of Ubuntu.

I have searched far and wide for how to recover the audio functionality to absolutely no avail (I could list the links, but I would need to find them again and many were hidden in obscure corners of the interwebs).  This particular problem matches my exact condition, given it is the same laptop model (Lenovo Yoga 11e Chromebook; Glimmer), and has the exact same issue (I can listen via bluetooth, HDMI output, but not headphone jack or system speakers).  The audio control panel only shows six different HDMI audio outputs and sets up a Dummy Output by default.

Specifically, I see this issue on Lubuntu 20.4 LTS (kernel 5.11.0-27-generic on the USB drive), but NOT on Xubuntu 21.04 (kernel 5.11.0-16-generic on the USB drive and 5.11.0-40-generic on the system, with 5.11.0-38-generic as an alternate option on the system).  I did notice that when I did an update on the 21.04, the sound stopped working.  I then went back and chose NOT to update either Alsa or PulseAudio, and my sound works fine on it.  On the PulseAudio Volume Control for Xubuntu 21.04 (on-system) and both USB flavors it lists the proper card (chtmax98090) and everything works flawlessly.

The solution offered in the above article also fails.  I also copied the UCM2 folder from Xubuntu and attempted the above commands and that also has no effect.

---

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374078/primary-sound-card-not-detected-by-alsamixer) appears to be a similar situation to mine, as well.

### Xubuntu (where the audio works):

```
lspci -v | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller

aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtmax98090 [chtmax98090], device 0: 3 []
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtmax98090 [chtmax98090], device 1: Deep-Buffer Audio (*) []
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The end of my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` is verbatim as that in the post:

```
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
    options bt87x index=-2
    options cx88_alsa index=-2
    options saa7134-alsa index=-2
    options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
    options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
    options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
    options snd-usb-audio index=-2
    options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
    options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
    options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
    options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
    # Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
    options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
    # Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
    options snd-pcsp index=-2
    # Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
    options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

And my AlsaMixer gives two devices.
Selection Menu:

```
      Sound Card
-  (default)  
0  HDA Intel PCH  
1  chtmax98090 
   enter device name...
```

Each one described as below:

```
Card: HDA Intel PCH
Chip: Intel Valleyview2 HDMI
View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All
Item: S/PDIF

   [00]     [00]
< S/PDIF >S/PDIF 1
```

AND

```
Card: chtmax98090
Chip:
View: F3: Playback  F4: Capture  F5:[All]
Item: Headphone [dB gain: -31.00, -31.00]
```

With many level controls that are scrollable below that.

As for `lspci -nn | grep -i audio`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [8086:0f04] (rev 0e)
```

### Now, for Lubuntu (where audio does NOT work; keep in mind this is running from the USB drive):

```
lspci -v | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller

aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtmax98090 [chtmax98090], device 0: 3 []
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtmax98090 [chtmax98090], device 1: Deep-Buffer Audio (*) []
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The end of my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` is verbatim as that in the post:

```
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
    options bt87x index=-2
    options cx88_alsa index=-2
    options saa7134-alsa index=-2
    options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
    options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
    options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
    options snd-usb-audio index=-2
    options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
    options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
    options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
    options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
    # Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
    options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
    # Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
    options snd-pcsp index=-2
    # Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
    options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

And my AlsaMixer gives two devices.
Selection Menu:

```
      Sound Card
-  (default)  
0  HDA Intel PCH  
1  chtmax98090 
   enter device name...
```

Each one described as below:

```
Card: HDA Intel PCH
Chip: Intel Valleyview2 HDMI
View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All
Item: PCM [dB gain: 0.00, 0.00]

 100<>100   [00]    [00]
<  PCM   > S/PDIF S/PDIF 1
```

AND

```
Card: chtmax98090
Chip:
View: F3: Playback  F4: Capture  F5:[All]
Item: Headphone [dB gain: 0.00, 0.00]
```

With many level controls that are scrollable below that.

As for `lspci -nn | grep -i audio`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [8086:0f04] (rev 0e)
```

---

With them being mostly the same results, I'm not sure what to do.

It's very curious to me why the chtmax98090 is seen under both flavors of Ubuntu, but only audible with Xubuntu.

Edit: Maybe now that I am ONLY mentioning flavors of Ubuntu, you can focus on the problem instead of whining about 'off-topic' comments.

Edit: Cleaned up some of original post and added kernel versions.

---

After some more digging into Alsa, I believe I can rule it out as the culprit.  While audio-working Xubuntu 21.04 uses Alsa 1.2.4 and audio-not-working Lubuntu 20.04 LTS uses Alsa 1.2.2, *unmentionable data points* suggest at least this alone is not the issue (i.e. one uses Alsa 1.2.4, but still no sound).

The only other thing I can think of is the listing of the chtmax98090 in the PulseAudio mixer.  As given in the first example, I only see a Dummy output under Lubuntu.

---

I hope to have a second machine of the same model by the weekend.  There, I plan to install Lubuntu and compare and contrast the two flavors side-by-side instead of needing to reboot for continued testing.  I am hopeful this can give me more insight as I continue to seek assistance here.

Comment: All of the distros mentioned in the question except Lubuntu and Xubuntu are off-topic here. You may want to edit those out and focus on Ubuntu or official Ubuntu derivatives only. Otherwise your question will be ignored and/or closed.

Comment: I include them to give better context.  This grants the understanding that it's not /specifically/ an Ubuntu issue.  Also, Mint and Kodachi at least started based on Ubuntu.
But, wow, if you guys are going to gate-keep a valid troubleshooting question, I can just rule out this community as helpful.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *I find it hard to understand what you're actually using and asking about, as most OSes you mention are off-topic on this site. If you have one on thumb-drive that works; that is your answer as you can compare what is used on that system (kernel modules etc) to fix the other OSes, but your question to me is confusing with most of it off-topic on this site*

Comment: You've not been very precise with details; Ubuntu LTS releases are offered with two kernel stack choices; if you use the GA kernel it'll remain the same for the life of the product, where if you install using a ISO that contains the HWE kernel stack as default, it changes during the first ~two years of the life; meaning after upgrading & reboot. The same applies with Xubuntu or Lubuntu. Ubuntu & all *flavors* (Lubuntu, Xubuntu etc) use the same kernels, have the identical same stack choices; though installed default can vary for 20.04 & on on ISO used to install, & can be changed post-install

Comment: Thank you for endeavoring to assist me with my issue. I have installed (both flavors) using ISO's applied to USB drives via rufus. The versions are mentioned above. I will add in the kernel versions to the original post. To save you the hassle, Lubuntu is 5.11.0-27-generic, while Xubuntu is 5.11.0-40-generic. At Grub, Xubuntu's advanced options also offer 5.11.0-38-generic. Of course, from the USB, Lubuntu does not offer another option. Also, the USB I installed Xubuntu from has kernel 5.11.0-16-generic (and sound still works).

Comment: Interestingly, I did some digging into Alsa, and found that both USB and system Xubuntu were running 1.2.4, while USB Lubuntu was running 1.2.2.  Looking at [this](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/focal/main/updates/alsa-utils), it seems to suggest that 1.2.2 is the proper version for Ubuntu 20.04, but no mention for 21.04.  
Unmentionable datapoints began to suggest it as an Alsa issue (1.1.3 and 1.2.2), but the last (1.2.4) forced return to the drawing board...

Comment: Ubuntu ISOS (including *flavors*) are built from packages; and all are built from the same packages; but are built at a set time. 20.04 means the 2020-April release; 21.04 means the 2021-April release. With *respins* a new ISO is spun; ie. 20.04.1 is a re-spin of 20.04 with later packages; 20.04.2 etc... For 20.04 I'd expect `alsa-base | 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5 | focal   | all` but online you can search using https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=alsa&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all   Note: each release uses only it's own packages (using the codename of the release; *focal* = 20.04)

Comment: Re-spins of LTS ISOs also have different kernel (& video) stacks on them once the .2 has been released; ie. 20.04.2 used the kernel stack from 20.10; 20.04.3 used the kernel stack from 21.04, 20.04.4 uses the kernel stack from 21.10 etc (20.04.4 is still in QA/testing). https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack so being precise (20.04 or 20.04.1? or 20.04.2? 20.04.3? etc) matters esp. if using *live* media.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `sudo dmesg | grep audio` and see direct firmware load failed errors, then try manually copying `sof-bin` firmware to `/lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg/` folder. See instructions in the answer of [no sound due to error direct firmware load failed for intel/sof-tplg/sof-byt-max98090.tplg](https://askubuntu.com/q/1383051/581796)

*(I am not a developer, just a regular user who encountered a similar problem. )*